# Is iTunes full screen mode bad for an LCD TV?

Tags: itunes, hdmi, dvi, hdtv

My 2 year old Samsung LCD TV just died after 2 years with no issue and perfect service.
It happened while I was listening to some music using iTunes in Coverflow mode in full screen. My computer was plugged into the TV using a DVI to HDMI cable.

Here is my question: is iTunes Coverflow full screen mode using a different screen resolution than the default desktop one?

Is it bad for an LCD TV connected via a DVI to HDMI cable to switch from a resolution to another a few times a day?

I'm just trying to see if my usage of iTunes in fullscreen mode is linked to my TV issue, or if it's only bad luck.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3):

The TV should not be affected by you using iTunes in fullscreen Coverflow mode. The worst thing that could happen to your TV in such a case would be if you get burn-in (the same static image, such as the fullscreen iTunes controls, become burned into the image, creating a sort of ghost of the static image).

Other than that, I can't really see a clear connection between iTunes and your TV dieing.

Comment: Do burn-in's still happen on modern LCD-Screens? I always thought that had something to do with the phosporous coating of old CRTs.

Comment: I check out the electronics department of large stores quite frequently. I've seen a lot of TVs with burn-in because they usually forget the DVDs at the menu screen and forget to hit play. You'd be surprised how often it happens, unfortunately.

Comment: I have never personally seen LCDs with burn-in. I have screens at work that display a 99.9% static image for 24 hours a day, every day. They have no burn-in at all. Also, when I worked at a retail outlet with LCDs, we left the menus on at times and never had burn-in, even on plasma sets.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the TV itself. Some TVs do not like switching modes again and again. If you give the model number it may be easier to say for sure, but I would say the switching (since it is a Samsung) would not be related to the death of the TV. You also don't say how the TV died. Since it's LCD, did the backlight go out? or did the power supply go out? If it was anything other than a logic board, I would bet on it not being iTunes that caused it.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.
The Samsung repair center call back: they had to replace a board (B Board or something like that).
The symptoms were that the TV switch ON for 20 seconds, then switch OFF by itself with a clicking sound.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly safe, the burn-in alex mentions occures only to CRT and Plasma displays...

Comment: Well, I didn't say it's the cause of the problem, I only said that's the worst it could happen. I doubt you could kill a TV by just leaving coverflow in fullscreen.

Comment: Sure, I agree with you, I just wanted to say that event "the worst thing" IMHO couldn't happen... :) I have phrased it a bit bad way I guess, English is not my mother language as you can see...